# Not able to create table with textField

Tags: django, django-models

I have model

```
from cgkapp.validators import validate_number

    # Create your models here.
    class Master_Questions(models.Model):
        Question_Number = models.AutoField(primary_key = True),
        Question_Text = models.TextField(max_length = 100),
        Option1 = models.TextField(max_length=50),
        Option2 = models.TextField(max_length=50),
        Option3 = models.TextField(max_length=50),
        Option4 = models.TextField(max_length=50),
        Answer = models.TextField(max_length=50),
        Difficulty_Level = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_number])
```

and my table is created as below. The textfields are not created.

```
sqlite> .schema cgkapp_master_questions
CREATE TABLE "cgkapp_master_questions" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "Difficulty_Level" integer NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `,` in Django to separate Model fields. Remove all `,` signs at the end of lines.